# How do you explain the change in population ratio of Germany vs. Switzerland since 1945?

Tags: economy, germany, population, switzerland

When you read newspapers nowadays, you'd get the opinion that the economy in Germany is doing "great".
However, when I plot the population development in Germany vs. Switzerland, I get a very different picture: continuous and relative drastic decline since 1945.

When you look at the period 1913-1918 and beyond, you see a timely-constrained decline that is probably related to WWI. If you consider that WWII was not that much worse than WWII, the trend should go upward since about at least 1970 to 1980. However, it continues downward.

So while Switzerland is prosperous, if Germany is so, too - how do you explain the decline ? I mean obviously that's because Switzerland is gaining faster or losing slower than Germany - but why ?

[image: Population ratio development]

Comment: Some ideas someone could develop into an answer: 1. Germany lost territory from WWII. 2. East Germany vs West Germany. 3. Aging population 4. Migration in and out of Germany 5. EU membership. 6. Swiss development (Switzerland has been doing quite well for quite some time).

Comment: Could you explain how the population ratio between the two countries is supposed to in any way indicate their respective prosperity?

Comment: I'm perplexed by the notion that change in population ratio is a more reliable indicator (or indeed any indicator) of change in relative prosperity than, say, GDP per capita?

Comment: Isn't this **completely backwards**? Ceterus parabus, it's an established fact that prosperity **lowers** birthrates

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick: Birthrates: "indigenous population" is declining in both countries. Country with higher-wages/lower-unemployment (aka better economy) gets more immigration.

Comment: @Quandary - there's some influence, but immigration policies and social safety net policies probably pay far more role than "prosperity".

Comment: Many germans imigrated and continues to immigrate into Switzerland; also while Germany has lots of immigration Switzerland has even more of it, also because the original population is much smaller in Switzerland, an influct of say 1000 people in both countries will increase the ratio even though both countries had the same amount of imigrants.

Comment: This also would be a better fit for economics.SE

Comment: Note that the population of Germany increased by almost 20% since end of WWII. The population of Switzerland increased even more, by almost 80 %.

Comment: @Bregalad: I think that's the actual explanation. An arithmetic pitfall so to say. It seems to be an indirect measurement of immigration rate ratio per capita - which apparently is much higher in Switzerland than in Germany.

Comment: @Bregalad Switzerland does not have more immigration than Germany, it's just a smaller country, that's not exactly the same.

Comment: @Relaxed: Exactly, but if you have the same nominal migration and are a lot smaller country, you have a much higher rate of migration per capita. Which means you actually have more perceived (and actual) immigration !

Comment: I struggle to see how the ratio of A and B should tell us anything especially when compared to the ratio of C and D. What about C/B, D/B, A/D, B/D? Why would A and B need to develop in a similar manner as C and D? What reasoning are you using? Also, what are your sources; can we re-create these graphs online?

Answer (score 11):

Population change is a function of birth rate, death rate and net migration.

Birth rates have declined in both Germany and Switzerland (at [almost identical rates](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.DYN.TFRT.IN?contextual=similar&locations=DE-CH)), but Switzerland has had more immigration relative to its population than Germany ([25% of the population of Switzerland](https://www.swissinfo.ch/eng/society/migration-series-part-1-_who-are-the-25-foreign-population-in-switzerland/42412156) is foreign born while [only 15% of the German population is foreign born](https://www.theglobalist.com/where-immigrants-move-global-north-germany-united-states/)), which comports very naturally with the well know fact that Swiss culture is more internationally oriented than the culture of Germany.

Germany also has had a [consistently higher death rate](https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SP.DYN.CDRT.IN?locations=DE-CH) than Switzerland (by a factor of about 2 deaths per 1000 population) for all of recent history, reflecting Switzerland's greater affluence (keep in mind that Germany includes former East Germany as well as former West Germany). Switzerland's per capita GDP is [about 22% higher](https://www.indexmundi.com/factbook/compare/switzerland.germany/economy) than Germany's.

This has been fostered by an overt Swiss policy of internationalism driven by its political neutrality, and by Switzerland not having a partial legacy of Soviet style Communism as the East German part of Germany does.

Comment: Could you provide some sources on the Birthrate and Immigration figures?

Comment: If I get a chance to provide sourcing today I will.

Comment: What is “internationally oriented culture” and “internationalism” supposed to mean exactly? Regard for international law, UN institutions and schools and facilities for the rich and famous? For better or for worse, Swiss culture is really insular in ways other countries in Western Europe are not, it makes no sense to me to consider it a more “internationally oriented culture”.

Comment: @Relaxed: Agree. That's an euphemism for tax-haven with multilingualism. I think the answer is that the graph is an indirect measurement of immigration rate ratio per capita. And because Switzerland's  population is low in comparison, the difference is made even more extreme in the ratio.

Comment: @Relaxed Although I agree ohwilleke statement is wrong/misleading, there's no such thing as "Swiss culture".

Comment: @Bregalad What do you mean? [Swiss culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Culture_of_Switzerland)

Comment: @user_42 I meant exactly what is written in the first intorductionary paragraph of the WP article you're linking to; in particular `The 26 cantons also account for the large cultural diversity`

Comment: @Bregalad And if you go further down, you will find the common actions/music/art that outsiders view as distinctly Swiss culture.

Comment: @Bregalad You can say that of many countries, very much including France, yet I still believe there is such a thing as Swiss culture.